# redirect virtualsubdomain to a page with same domain as parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

in a php code i need to redirect all virtual sub domain to a page with same sub domain as parameter.

example, redirect from :

```
anytext.mydomain.com
```

to :

```
mydomain.com/example.php?text="anytext"
```

how i can do it with htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

try this out it might help you for sure :

```
# .htaccess

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.your-domain-name.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).your-domain-name.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /some_file.php/$1?subdomain=%2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: can u post what exactly you used in your htaccess file ? it seems there is some other issue.